# How to take both number of enteries and search bar at the top in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable

[image]I have datatable I turned off its pagination now I want to show total enteries . Which displayed like `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries` and search bar at the top but when i take total enteries at top . Search bar goes down in the bottom

```
 $('#consignment_table').DataTable({
                        responsive: true,
                        "order": [],
                        "bSort": true,
                        scrollY: '50vh',
                        scrollX: true,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        "paging": false,
                        dom:'<"top"i>rt<"top"f><"clear">',

                        aLengthMenu: [
                            [-1],
                            ["All"]
                        ],
                        iDisplayLength: 5000
                    }).draw();
```

I want to take both total enteries and search bar at the top

Comment: Could you try the following: `'ifrt'`

Comment: yeah it works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom):

> DataTables will add a number of elements around the table to both
> control the table and show additional information about it. The
> position of these elements on screen are controlled by a combination
> of their order in the document (DOM) and the CSS applied to the
> elements. This parameter is used to control their ordering and
> additional mark-up surrounding them in the DOM.

- `l` - length changing input control
- `f` - filtering input
- `t` - The table!
- `i` - Table information summary
- `p` - pagination control
- `r` - processing display element

> Each option can be specified multiple times (with the exception of the
> table itself), which can be used to have table controls both above and
> below the table. DataTables will automatically synchronise these
> multiple controls.

So everything placed before the `t` will be placed above the dataTable and everything after it will be placed below the dataTable, so the desired behavior can be achieved with the following string: `ifrt`

```
$('#consignment_table').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    order: [],
    bSort: true,
    scrollY: '50vh',
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    dom: 'ifrt',
    aLengthMenu: [
        [-1],
        ["All"]
    ],
    iDisplayLength: 5000
}).draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi While Using DOM option in Datatable it will send your search bar at the bottom.
So you need some logic to show that search bar at top.

below is function

```
var dt;
$(document).ready(function() {
   dt= $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
         dom:'<"top"i>rt<"top"f>',
         "paging": false,
    } );
    setTimeout(adjustSearchbar,1200)
} );
function adjustSearchbar(){
    var searchBar=$("#example_wrapper > .top:last")
   $("#example_wrapper").prepend(searchBar.clone());
   $('input[type="search"]').keyup(function(){
      dt.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})
  searchBar.hide()
}
```

Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/4v2hqjo6/19/).

But some css fix you still need. :)